# Helper method returning entire hash in view instead of printing keys and values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my user profile view I have this:

```
#show.html.haml

%p
  %b Categories
  = list_self_reviews(current_user.self_reviews)
```

The `list_self_reviews` helper looks like this:

```
#profiles_helper.rb

  def list_self_reviews(reviews)
    self_reviews = {}
    reviews.each { |review| self_reviews["#{review.get_category_name}"] = "#{review.body}" } 

    self_reviews.each do |key, value|
      puts "#{key} (#{value})"
    end
  end
```

I'm creating a hash of review category names and the body of the review and trying to print them in the profile view in the format "[Category Name]: [Review Body]." However, in the view the entire hash is being printed out, so that it looks like this:

```
{"organizing"=>"I'm a pretty organized guy", "tutoring"=>"helped with spanish"}
```

It should just say "organizing: I'm a pretty organized guy" and then the other one below it. What am I missing here about how to return this correctly in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your profile view file(show.html.haml) as follows

```
  %p
    %b Categories
    - current_user.self_reviews.each do |review|
      = "[#{review.get_category_name}]: [#{review.body}]."
      %br/
```

Comment: @sixty4bit On another note, what does `get_category_name` do?

Comment: The Review is associated with a Category model so it has a `category_id` but I need to get the actual name, so it looks like this: `#review.rb   def get_category_name
   Category.find(self.category_id).name
  end`

Comment: But.......it looks like I should just be able to do `review.category.name` without making my own method for that  =)

Comment: @sixty4bit Yeah, otherwise it's a lot of calls to the db.

Comment: Best practice is to put `delegate :name, to: :category, prefix: true, allow_nil: :true` in your `Review` model. That allows you to do `review.category_name` and avoids problems you might have if category happens to be nil (look up Law of Demeter).

Comment: What if I don't have direct access to the view and must use Ruby code to generate text from an `.each` loop? For example, I am implementing ActiveAdmin and have this: `column "Names" do |job| job.workers.each do |jas| "#{jas.full_name}" end end` How do I get it to return the names of each worker in my AA column?

Answer (score 1):

It's what gets returned from the method that's important - that's what gets inserted into your HTML. `puts` is for outputting to the console only. Your method is implicitly returning the `self_reviews` hash because it is the last thing evaluated (with `self_reviews.each`). As it currently stands, you need to build a single string with all your list items (would likely need to contain HTML) and return that instead.

That being said, I feel like your code could be made neater with something like:

```
#show.html.haml

  %p
    %ul Categories
    - current_user.self_reviews.each do |review|
      %li = review_item(review)

#profiles_helper.rb

  def review_item(review)
    "#{review.get_category_name}: #{review.body}"
  end
```

...or even no helper at all (like the other answer).

**Edit** - or you could do something like this:

```
#show.html.haml

  %p
    = review_list

#profiles_helper.rb

  def review_list
    content_tag :ul, "Categories" do
      current_user.self_reviews.each do |review|
        content_tag :li, "#{review.get_category_name}: #{review.body}"
      end
    end
  end
```

but personally I prefer my template to be a bit more explicit, and you might be better off using a partial in this case.

Comment: Thanks. The part about `puts` being only for the console was helpful. Also I want to get a better feel for best practices surrounding issues like when to write a helper vs when to write out the code in my view template. Do you have any recommendations here? Can that be learned systematically through some resource somewhere or does it just come with experience?

Comment: Helpers are there to avoid too much logic in the views, or repetition. Iteration (`.each`) isn't what most people would class as too much logic, and even simple conditionals are sometimes ok, but most other logic you should at least consider trying to factor it into a helper. As for repetition, it just follows the same DRY principle as standard code - if there's an operation (usually a formatting one) that you need to do on a piece of text repeatedly in multiple places in your views, factor it out. However if you wanted to reuse, say, your list in multiple places, that's what partials are for.

Comment: To answer the last part of your question: there are certainly resources that touch on this, [railstutorial.org](http://www.railstutorial.org/book) is one I can name off the top of my head (it's a full-blown tutorial but I recommend it if you haven't done it already). [This blog post](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/1108-what-belongs-in-a-helper-method) might also be helpful, and I'm sure there's others you can find without too much trouble. But a lot of it does just come with experience, specifically practice with refactoring (when, where, how, what) in general.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I have gone through the Hartl tutorial already. I'm finding that there are plenty of beginners' resources but there doesn't seem to be much out there to take one through the intermediate level.